# Device claims external storage, yet I have no SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Samsung galaxy S3 with no SD card, I'm using this code to check storage states.

Using this code:

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```

So perhaps someone can explain to me if this phone for some reason treats it's internal memory as external?  Or what?

Answer (score 14):

**getExternalStorageDirectory doesn't always return the SDCard.**

Google doc says :

> "don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can
>   better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can
>   hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all
>   applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an
>   SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer."

There might be chances that "/mnt/sdcard" refers to the inbuilt storage for your phone.

It is better to check the **return path** from the `getExternalStorageDirectory` method whether it is external removable storage or not.

You can use [Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) for checking it.

Answer (score 2):

Android will always report **one** mounted hardware memory (if any available) as External Storage.

That memory can be:

1. fitted inside the device by manufacturer (internal memory)
2. can be an sd card (external memory)

A device can even have both, but Android will report only **one** of them (mostly internal one).

A simple way to get what is mounted where is `adb shell mount`.

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (ro)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
tmpfs on /mnt/asec type tmpfs (rw,mode=755,gid=1000)
tmpfs on /mnt/obb type tmpfs (rw,mode=755,gid=1000)
/dev/block/mtdblock2 on /system type yaffs2 (ro)
/dev/block/mtdblock3 on /data type yaffs2 (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/block/mtdblock1 on /cache type yaffs2 (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/block/vold/179:1 on /mnt/sdcard type vfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/block/vold/179:1 on /mnt/secure/asec type vfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```