# simple write file code works in java but not on android device

Tags: java, android, file-io

I tested this code and it works fine in java and writes a test file on my notebook computer, however can't get this to work on android device.

I put a note to show where the null pointer exception is.

When i run this on several different android devices the result is the same. It crashes with null pointer in the same line of code.

What would cause this to work with no errors on a java desktop application and get null pointer on an android device?

any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File makeDirectory = new File("/mnt/testDirectory/");

        // File makeDirectory = new File("C:/testDirectory/"); // when used on
        // java desktop app

        makeDirectory.mkdir();

        File file = new File("/mnt/testDirectory/testfile.txt");

        // File file = new File("C:/testDirectory/testfile.txt"); // when used
        // on java desktop app

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        PrintStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        output.print(true); // <----- NULL POINTER EXCEPTION THIS LINE
        output.print((int) 123);
        output.print((float) 123.456);

        output.printf(Locale.UK, "Text + data: %1$", 123);

        output.close();

    }
}
```

---

permissions from the manifest xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

EDIT: I just found some additional information, so I am not afraid of using getExternalStorageDirectory()  because if i am correct. all Android devices have some external storage directory on them, even if not SD card is used, example from the other question i found,

```
"Android will always report one mounted hardware memory (if any available) as External Storage.

That memory can be:

fitted inside the device by manufacturer (internal memory)
can be an sd card (external memory)
```

From this question:

[Device claims external storage, yet I have no SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556902/device-claims-external-storage-yet-i-have-no-sd-card)

Comment: that's not how you access the external file storage. See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how you get a file from external storage:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);
```

Note:

> may be if your device is rooted. mnt could work. I have no idea. but,
>   it is a wrong approach.

Comment: will this work even if there is no SD card inserted in the SD card slot?

Comment: i understand that some android devices have /mnt/sdcard/ is really not a real SD card,  sdcard is just a folder on internal memory. not an actual hardware SD card,  but is it possible for an adroid device to have nothing for Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory.  in other words nothing that would be considered external

Comment: i have faith, i believe

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 1):

Ahem, '/mnt'?
As per all the tutorials i've come across and also the android developers website;
You need to use:

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() method which returns a File object containing a reference to the root storage directory. From there on; if you're a good java programmer I think you can handle the rest ;)